# Add Language in Xcode 14.1 Simulator problem

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode14

I updated my Xcode to 14.1. but when I want to add a language in Setting, it stays on this page and I can't do any thing.

All I can do is Erase All content and Setting to return to normal state. It works on my MacBook Air M1, but no on my MacBook Pro 2019 Intel i7

[image]

Comment: Same problem on the same macbook ((

Comment: I hit the same issue. Changing region or language caused the home screen app in simulator hung (activity monitor app on macOS shows that SpringBoard process took a high percentage of CPU time). Mine is MacBook Pro 2017, though that probably doesn't matter. it seems a common issue of XCode 14.1. I have filed FB11762782.

Comment: Have you found a fix? This problem is annoying.

Comment: Is this problem still exist in Xcode 14.2?

Answer (score 7):

It works on M1/M2 but it doesn't on Intel. You can use the command line tool `simctl` as a workaround.
To set the preferred language to e.g. "German" use the following command:

`xcrun simctl spawn <UUID> defaults write "Apple Global Domain" AppleLanguages -array de`

To change the region use:

`xcrun simctl spawn <UUID> defaults write "Apple Global Domain" AppleLocale -string 'de_DE'`

Replace `<UUID>` with the `UUID` of the device you want to change. To get the currently booted device(s) use:

`xcrun simctl list 'devices' 'booted'`

After you have changed language and/or region you need to shutdown and reboot the device like this.

`xcrun simctl shutdown <UUID>` followed by `xcrun simctl boot <UUID>`

If you only want to change the currently booted device(s) you can just use `'booted'` instead of the UUID. Like so:

`xcrun simctl shutdown 'booted'`

So, to change the preferred language of the currently booted device(s) to English, just use:

`xcrun simctl spawn 'booted' defaults write "Apple Global Domain" AppleLanguages -array en`

To change language and/or region the desired device(s) must be booted.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.
setting the preferred language went smoothly, but for the region I had to resort to the plutil command, which can also be used to set the language (credits: https://nshipster.com/simctl/):
PLIST=~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$UDID/data/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist

LANGUAGE="ja"
LOCALE="ja_JP"

plutil -replace AppleLocale -string $LOCALE $PLIST
plutil -replace AppleLanguages -json "[ \"$LANGUAGE\" ]" $PLIST

Comment: do you checked it with Xcode 14.2? still exist?

Comment: @Sajjad I just checked with Xcode 14.2 and it worked by using the Settings App of the Simulator - at least it worked for me!