# iPhone iOS 16.1 simulator hangs when changing the language or region

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode 14.1 and iPhone 14 Simulator (iOS 16.1) on macOS Ventura 13.0.1.

For some reason, the simulator comes in English, however the previous versions defaulted to my native language (which is a system language in macOS).

If I debug the app I'm currently working on, the Preferred Languages list (defined by `CFBundleLocalizations`) is missing.

When I'm trying to change the simulator's language or region, it just hangs on "Setting language..." or "Setting region...". If I wait, a crash report appears which is related to Springboard:

```
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro15,1
Process:             SpringBoard [39407]
Path:                /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier:          com.apple.springboard
Version:             1.0 (50)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [36363]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.C20800F7-3C7B-4C62-83FB-DF67A3BD8D3A [2845]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [7758]

Date/Time:           2022-11-29 14:14:46.1258 +0100
Launch Time:         2022-11-29 14:08:49.3676 +0100
OS Version:          macOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fe09b8fc000
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00007fe09b8fc000
VM Region Info: 0x7fe09b8fc000 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 1  Bytes before following region: 33854341120
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_LARGE             7fe09a0e6000-7fe09b8fc000 [ 24.1M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  GAP OF 0x7e1e04000 BYTES
      MALLOC_TINY              7fe87d700000-7fe87d800000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [39407]
```

Restarting the simulator leads to a black screen and infinite loading, and if I erase content and settings, it just returns to its basic configuration (English (US) / USA), but after that I still can't set region or language.

Restarting macOS doesn't help, reinstalling Xcode doesn't help, removing local simulator files doesn't help, and it seems nobody has the same issue...

**iOS 16.0 Simulator is fine.**

Comment: I've noticed this too, but it hardly seems like a Stack Overflow question. File a bug report with Apple.

Comment: @matt I did file it, but maybe it's not even a bug and just my problem. Maybe someone has some workaround, maybe there's some cache that can be cleared, maybe some script should be ran to fix the broken state. There are questions regarding Simulator's problems on SO, there were plenty problems with it in the last decade, that's why I'm asking here as well

Comment: No, I don't think so. As I say, I've seen this issue myself.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299410/add-language-in-xcode-14-1-simulator-problem

Comment: I can confirm that we're experiencing the same issue